# localstorage not working when openBrowserWindow is used in office word add in

Tags: local-storage, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have a word addin in angular. I am using openBrowserWindow to open a new window with a html file. Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow("http://someurl/hello.html");

I have set some value in the localstorage in the application but the localstorage value is null when i am trying to fetch from the new window opened with the html file.

Note:

1. I can access the localstorage value within the application but not in the new window
2. Application and html are in the same domain

This uses edge internally.

Comment: What code do you use or tried so far?

Comment: I just set the localstorage like localstorage.setItem("test","testvalue") in the application before opening the new window and tried to access the value in the html within the script with localstorage.getItem("test"). I also cannot see the localstorage value in the developer tools as well. But i can access this value within the application. Also if i set some value in the html, i can access them inside the html itself.